# How to select default value Ultragrid column cell drop down list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ultrawingrid

I have loaded Ultra Grid and set New Column Cell List using
Following code:

```
UltraGridColumn column = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1];

// Create a value list.
ValueList vl1 = new ValueList( );
vl1.ValueListItems.Add( 1, "True" );
vl1.ValueListItems.Add( 2, "False" );

// Set vl1 to the column2. Cells in column2 will use this value list.
column.ValueList = vl1;
```

I want vl1.selectedvalue = 2 Load For Default value, which I'm not able to achieve. Any help and guidance is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.ValueList~SelectedIndex.html

You need to set the SelectedIndex of your ValueList:

```
ValueList list = new ValueList();
list.ValueListItems.Add(1,"One");
list.ValueListItems.Add(2,"Two");
list.ValueListItems.Add(3,"Three");
list.ValueListItems.Add(4,"Four");

list.SelectedIndex = 2;
list.SortStyle = ValueListSortStyle.AscendingByValue ;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].ValueList = list;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @kari kalan If this doesn't help, please respond with an update. If this does help, please accept as answer.